# Why do GPU's often have a different core frequency and shader frequency?

Tags: frequency, gpu

Typically GPU's have a faster core frequency and shader frequency. Typically the shader frequency is double or more than double that of the core frequency (e.g. 607 MHz and 1215MHz for GeForce GTX 590). What is the reason for this?

ps. I'm not sure if this is the right stackexchange site for this question.

Comment: the shaders are very simple processors. They are designed to be highly clockable. I'm not sure what parts of the very complex system-on-chip a GPU is you subsume under "core" ("the shaders" is already not really how groups of functional units in GPUs are structured, but more of a software view on things), but I guess it's more of a central management unit that coordinates the work, than doing the math itself. So it makes sense these things are separate and not clocked the same.

Comment: Most GPUs do not have separate core and shader clocks anymore, Nvidia stopped that a decade ago.

Comment: Clock domain crossings are expensive and error-prone. There wasn't too much communication between core and shader, so you could split them to separate frequencies and optimize each for optimal pipeline depth separately.

Answer (score 0):

IF shaders work at 2x resolution on a frame buffer averaging 4 pixels and computing anti-aliasing shades on sharp edges, background and foreground with some algorithm , it must be faster than the pixel raw rendering.

Comment: This doesn't explain the frequency difference, as opposed to simply parallelism difference.